# Errors appear after changing code generation from none to default in entity framework 5

Tags: .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a wpf project 4.5 and I am using EF 5 to generate the model classes.  I want to implement iNotifyPropertyChanged for the EF classes gererated.  So I right clicked in my designer (visual studio 2012) and changed the code generation setting from "None" to "Default"

Once I did that I got hundreds of errors like the following:

> Error 67  'Public Property *"TableColumnName"* As *"ColumnType"* has multiple
>   definitions with identical signatures.

[EDIT 1]

These errors are all being thrown in the DataModel.Designer.Vb file.  They occur on any table column property or navigation property that have the same name as a column/navigation property in another table.  I find it hard to believe that I can't have columns in different tables with the same names, something else must be going on here.

[EDIT 2]

So I removed all my database objects from the designer, then changed the code generation strategy to default, then added one table (client) to the diagram.  I am getting lots of errors for every property of the table (so this must not be because other tables have the same column names as I previously thought).  I am getting the error I listed above on EVERY property(table column) as well as the following error for EVERY property:

> Error variable '_ColumnName' conflicts with a member implicitly
>   declared for property 'ColumnName' in class
>   'client'. C:...\FTC_DAL.Designer.vb

This goes away when I return the code generation back to none.  I am staring to think this is a bug in EF 5.

[EDIT 3]

STEPS TO REPRODUCE:

1. Create new project in Visual Studio 2012, wpf application.
   It can be vb or c, i tested both
2. Add a ADO.NET entity data model (edmx file)
3. Add a table from a sql server (I am using express 2008 R2)
4. Build the project and then click in the edmx designer on blank space.  In properties window, change **code generation strategy** to *default* instead of *none*.
5. Build project and the errors will appear.

I am using:

- visual studio 2012 pro v.11.0.51106.01 update 1
- .NET 4.5.50709
- Windows 8 pro

I am going to install sql server 2012 express to see if this makes any difference

Can someone help me figure out why these errors are happening.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having the Code Generation Strategy at "None" is correct, you should leave it like that.

When you change it to "Default", you get classes for all the entities in your model. However, you are already getting those same classes from the `.tt` templates. As a result, you're getting all the class members twice.

In order to change how the classes get generated, *still* leave Code Generation Strategy at "None", as the default code generation is not customisable anyway. The `Model.tt` file can be freely modified to suit your needs, and it should not take too much effort to modify that to make your classes implement any interface you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I understand what you are saying, so I tried to delete the model.tt file to see if that resolved the errors.  It did not, even when the classes were only declared in the model.designer.vb file, the errors were still present.  as for leaving the strategy as none, the reason I changed it was because I am trying to provide data validation to the user as they enter data per property/textbox.  I am using database/model first with EF 5 and am having trouble accomplishing this.  All the example I find are code first where people create their own propertychangedevents.

Comment: Ran out of room, continued: With model first, the classes do not have built in propertychanged events and I was trying to implement that by changing the code generation.  I realize this is not ideal but I really can not find a good example of model first data validation with EF 5 that allows for validation as the user input data in a form.  I think i will have to open another question for this topic.

Comment: @JKing Updated my answer, although I would like to note that removing the `Model.tt` file (and `Model.Context.tt` and generated `.cs` files) should have got rid of the errors; at worst, it should have introduced other errors, but you should not continue to see the old ones.

Comment: I did look into the solution of changing the template and was unsuccessful, because all the examples I found were for EF 4.x  and the EF 5 DBContext creates a different template then EF4.   I could not find an example on how to change the template to include iNotifyPropertyChnaged and I am new to Entity Framework so I also could not figure out how to change it myself.  I would greatly appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: @JKing If you remove the `.tt` files, right-click in the EDMX designer, and choose "Add Code Generation Item", you can search online for other templates than the default. Look for "EF 5.x STE Generator for C#", one of the differences with the default template is that this one already implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. You can, if you wish, compare that to the `.tt` you had before to see how it's done.

Comment: So a little more history, I was using the self tracing entities that you proposed, but then I noticed on the following [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj613668) that they are no longer supported.  I understand that EF5 is the preferred approach with the more lightweight POCO. So I am trying to switch over and the only problem I am having is with data validation.  Maybe EF5 has a better way of doing it that using the NotifyPropertyChanged events.  I am currently reading about DataAnnotations, but they are proving difficult to implement in a database first approach.

Comment: @JKing For generic calculated properties (and data validation can be considered a special case of that: a calculated `IsXXXValid` / `XXXErrors` property), I know of no better way than using `PropertyChanged`. Yes, STEs add a lot you don't need, but they get you started. You can (later, if you want) use the STE `.tt` file as a basis for modifying the default `.tt` file, so that you only take the `INotifyPropertyChanged` bits and not the rest.

Comment: thanks, that is what I needed to know.  I just didn't want to get caught too deep into development with a strategy that either isn't supported, or is wrong.  I realize that there are a lot of ways to accomplish these tasks (ie data validation).  So... the answer is as you said, leave the code generation as none (removing errors), and then edit the .tt template to include iNotifyPropertyChanged.  I will use the STE .tt as a starting point.

Comment: When you delete the .tt-Files how do you get all the methods (like factory methods)? Looks to me you are forced to use pocos or write a lot of code by yourself that would usually be provided by the .tt files. Any solution for that?

Answer (score 7):

Refer the following link. I spent a lot of time getting frustrated with this issue and found this support article from the link that shows up on the 'add domain service class' screen right after 'Some ... may be missing'...

The summary of the observation is that WCF RIA does not support DBContext (indicated by the .tt files). To use the Domain service class, ObjectContext classes are needed. Here's the resolution from the [support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2745294).

> In order to utilize your Entity Framework model with WCF RIA Services, you must convert it to an 'ObjectContext' based model. This can be done using the following steps:
>
> 1. Open your entity model in the designer
> 2. (If needed, click in the "white space" of the designer to ensure no objects within the model are selected)
> 3. In the Properties window, change the "Code Generation Strategy" from "None" to "Default"
> 4. Delete the two ".tt" files that are adjacent to the model, with the assumption that you have not modified these files beyond their original state when the entity model was created. If you have modified these files, then customizations to your entity model will be lost.
> 5. Rebuild the project
>
> After following those steps, you will be able to select your entity model's context class  in the 'Available context classes' list. The side-effect of this procedure is that you have now converted your entity model from an Entity Framework DbContext-based model to an ObjectContext-based model.

Comment: +1 for following up on an older question.  I changed my approach to use partial classes extending the basic db first generated classes.