# Entity Framework Code Generation Strategy generates errors

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I installed Entity Framework 6 and am using Visual Studio 2012 to practice with it. I created a WPF application and added a ADO.NET Entity Data Model to connect to a MySQL database that I have on localhost. In the properties of the design (of the data model), I changed to the value of "Code Generation Strategy" to "default," so that it generates code in `Model1.Designer.cs` for me. But the code that it generates has errors:

```
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // <auto-generated>
    //    This code was generated from a template.
    //
    //    Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
    //    Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
    // </auto-generated>
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data.EntityClient;
    using System.Data.Objects;
    using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

    [assembly: EdmSchemaAttribute()]
    #region EDM Relationship Metadata

    [assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("SchoolDBModel", "studentcourse", "course", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, typeof(WpfApplication1.course), "student", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, typeof(WpfApplication1.student))]

    #endregion

    namespace WpfApplication1
    {
        #region Contexts

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        public partial class SchoolDBEntities : ObjectContext
        {
            #region Constructors

            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new SchoolDBEntities object using the connection string found in the 'SchoolDBEntities' section of the application configuration file.
            /// </summary>
            public SchoolDBEntities() : base("name=SchoolDBEntities", "SchoolDBEntities")
            {
                this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
                OnContextCreated();
            }
    // More code below with errors...
```

The first error is the base call in the constructor, that says

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext.DbContext(string, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbCompiledModel)' has some invalid arguments

And the next error is the line where it's setting `this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled`, it says

> 'WpfApplication1.SchoolDBEntities' does not contain a definition for 'ContextOptions' and no extension method 'ContextOptions' accepting a first argument of type 'WpfApplication1.SchoolDBEntities' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Does anyone know why it's generating code with errors?

Comment: This usually indicates that there is code that was generated when the generation strategy was "none". I bet there's still a Model1.tt and Model1.Context.tt that you have to remove.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Errors appear after changing code generation from none to default in entity framework 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865038/errors-appear-after-changing-code-generation-from-none-to-default-in-entity-fram)

Comment: That fixed everything. THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download
Entity Framework 6 Tools for Visual Studio 2012 & 2013

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40762

as described in
[Entity Framework Designer Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15051138/entity-framework-designer-errors)

Comment: Gert Arnold's comment already solved it for me, but I'll accept your answer since I wasn't able to accept his.

Answer (score 0):

In Entity Framwork6 you can use legacy context. Just right click the edmx file and in open with option open it in XML viewer. Then search for legacy and set the value of it as true.